# Iphone does not recognize reneweed ad hoc provising profile

Tags: iphone, profile, provisioning, adhoc

I installed a new version of an app we are developing, and also a new ad hoc provisioning profile (the old one had expired). I removed the app and profile from the phone and from itunes. Added the new profile and app to itunes and synched. All seemed well- the new profile was on the phone and the new app too. But when trying to launch the app, I get an alert: "the application cannot be opened because the provisioning profile has expired".

I removed and reinstalled. I rebooted the phone. Nothing helped.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

OK- found a solution: I had to REMOVE EVERY EXPIRED Profile on my phone. Even though the profile I was using was new and not expired, I could only run my app after I removed all expired profiles from the phone- even those that had nothing to do with my app.

Another little bug for iPhone OS.

Comment: I did the same thing. I'm sure there's a better solution, but I was in a hurry.

Comment: Worked for me too. Crazy. Cheers for figuring that out and saving me hours of rage.

Comment: Unfortunately, this IS the best solution.  What a pain!

Answer (score 0):

After an evening of trying all the deletes and replacing of profiles that Amnon did, I too finally solved the problem by removing the expired profile from my iPad Touch. But it took me until this morning to find out how to do that. To do that, download and install the iPhone Configuration Utility from Apple. This was the missing bit of info in the answer, so I'm posting it here.
http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/

Comment: You don't actually need the iPhone Configuration Utility; you can do it on the device itself.  On the iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch, go to Settings -> General -> Provisioning, then select the expired profiles and tap remove.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also remove provisioning profiles from devices (iphone/ipad/ipod touch) through Xcode's "Organizer" window, when the device is connected to the mac that is running Xcode. (There are [+][-] buttons below the device's "Provisioning" window in the Summary tab of the Organizer window.)